# What is The Best Google Cloud Solution For Serving Our Website

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

We've recently moved our not for profit organisation over to Google Workspace and have just overhauled the website.  Everything has been developed on Compute Engine, Its a basic wordpress site so no problems there..

Now its getting close to launch time and I'm thinking about the traffic.  We get approximately 25-30,000 visitors a day so I want to make sure I have enough resources to handle this.

I have set up App engine with 4 cores and 16GB in a flexible environment but I'm second guessing this.  We signed up for Google standard support to see if we could get some guidance from there wbut we had no luck - I cannot submit a ticket so thought I would ask the comunity.

Does anybody have any suggestions on what the best set up would be for us?
Many thanks in advance
Matt

Comment: Why do you want to switch from Compute Engine? That is a very good platform for WordPress and MySQL. Note: I would not consider 25K visitors per day a problem. If you have a 4 core 16 GB setup, that is usually more than enough for 100K+ visitors . Monitor CPU and Memory usage and page response time.

Comment: Thank you John.  I panicked a little bit while obviously overthinking things !  I’ll switch back to compute engine today before launch.  Thank you for your guidance

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @John Hanley:

> That is a very good platform for WordPress and MySQL. Note: I would not consider 25K visitors per day a problem. If you have a 4 core 16 GB setup, that is usually more than enough for 100K+ visitors . Monitor CPU and Memory usage and page response time.

---

In addition, Compute Engine provides more flexibility and, in general, is less expensive than App Engine. The disadvantage is that you are responsible for managing your virtual machines and app.

[Read more about Compute Engine](http://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/)

Reference:

- [View and understand VM instance insights](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/view-and-understand-vm-insights)

Comment: Thank you Chanpols … appreciate your input … I will go back to compute engine.  Thank you for your guidance